# Php equivalent hash_hmac function in Android

Tags: android, hash

I have looking around for a php equivalent hash_hmac function for android, my php function is something like this

```
$sharedSecret = "YSHSHAJKD==";
$URL = "http://sadas.com";
hash_hmac("sha1", $URL, base64_decode($sharedSecret))
```